# How to change dynamically height of central DIV depending on another DIVs?

Tags: html, css

I'm sorry in advance for my English!

At first, I had the following document structure:

```
<div class="wrapper w-100">
  <div class="top w-100">TOP</div>
  <div id="container" class="middle w-100">MIDDLE</div>
  <div class="bottom w-100">BOTTOM</div>
</div>
```

The CSS is corresponding to the structure above:

```
.w-100 {
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 420px;
}
.top {
  background-color:  #DAF7A6 ;
  height: 42px;
}
.middle {
  background-color:  #FF5733 ;
  height: calc(100% - 42px - 42px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.bottom {
  background-color:  #C70039 ;
  height: 42px;
}
```

It is working perfectly.

But now I should use another structure with "ghost" element.
It is rendered dynamically and controlled by java-script:

```
<div class="wrapper w-100">
  <div class="top w-100">TOP</div>
  <div class="ghost w-100">GHOST</div>
  <div id="container" class="middle w-100">MIDDLE</div>
  <div class="bottom w-100">BOTTOM</div>
</div>
```

If I use the old CSS the height of "wrapper" element increases after "ghost" element was append to a document.

What should I do to make possible the height of "middle" element to change automatically while "ghost" element is appearing/disappearing.
The height of "wrapper" element shouldn't change its own value.
I don't want to use java-script for that.

Thank you in advance!

[My fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AntonMV/tv3xbg41/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
function gen(n) {
 container = document.getElementById('container')
 for (var i=0; i<n; ++i) {
   var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.append('INNER ELEMENT # ' + i);
    div.className = 'inner';
   container.appendChild(div)
  }
}

function toggle() {
 var ghost = document.getElementById('ghost')
  if (ghost.style.display == "none") {
    ghost.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    ghost.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function blink(s) {
  toggle()
  setTimeout(function(){blink(s)}, s)
}

gen(10);
blink(2000);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}
.w-100 {
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  background-color: #fff;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  height: 300px;
}
.top {
  background-color:  #DAF7A6 ;
  height: 42px;
}


.ghost {
  background-color: #FFC300;
  height: 42px;
}
.middle {
  background-color:  #FF5733 ;
  /*height: calc(100% - 42px - 42px);*/
  flex:1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.bottom {
  background-color:  #C70039 ;
  height: 42px;
}
.inner {
  height: 42px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper w-100">
  <div class="top w-100">TOP</div>
  <div id="ghost" class="ghost w-100">GHOST</div>
  <div id="container" class="middle w-100">MIDDLE</div>
  <div class="bottom w-100">BOTTOM</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS only you can do this like this.

```js
function gen(n) {
  container = document.getElementById('container')
  for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.append('INNER ELEMENT # ' + i);
    div.className = 'inner';
    container.appendChild(div)
  }
}

function toggle() {
  var ghost = document.getElementById('ghost')
  if (ghost.style.display == "none") {
    ghost.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    ghost.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function blink(s) {
  toggle()
  setTimeout(function() {
    blink(s)
  }, s)
}

gen(10);
blink(2000);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}

.w-100 {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 300px;
}

.top {
  background-color: #DAF7A6;
  height: 42px;
}

.ghost {
  position: absolute;
  top: 42px;
  background-color: #FFC300;
  height: 42px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.middle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 84px;
  background-color: #FF5733;
  height: calc(100% - 42px - 42px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin-top: -42px;
  padding-top: 42px;
}

.bottom {
  background-color: #C70039;
  height: 42px;
}

.inner {
  height: 42px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper w-100">
  <div class="top w-100">TOP</div>
  <div id="ghost" class="ghost w-100">GHOST</div>
  <div id="container" class="middle w-100">MIDDLE</div>
  <div class="bottom w-100">BOTTOM</div>
</div>
```